# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with loader component when calling it from ngOnInit() of any component

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with a loader component. It works fine but I get a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when calling it from ngOnInit() of any component. This is my code:

loader.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'csm-loader',
  template: `<div [hidden]="!isLoading"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x"></i> <span>{{message}}</span></div>`
})
export class LoaderComponent {
  @Input() isLoading = false;
  @Input() message: string;

  constructor() { }
}
```

loader.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {
  loading = false;

  constructor() { }

  start() {
    this.loading = true;
  }

  stop() {
    this.loading = false;
  }

  isLoading() {
    return this.loading;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
    ...

    constructor(
    ...
    private loaderService: LoaderService
  ) { }

  ...
}
```

app.component.html:

```
...
<csm-loader *ngIf="loaderService.isLoading()" [isLoading]="loaderService.isLoading()"></csm-loader>
```

Then if I call `this.loaderService.start();` from `ngOnInit()` of a component it works fine but I get the following console error:
**ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.**

How can I fix that error?

Comment: You need to understand how change detection works to solve this problem. https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4. This article explains the issue and provide solutions.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?